# HTTP 500 Error When running a workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library

I have created a workflow that takes the version number (major and minor) of a document, truncates it to give only the major number and put it into another column in the library.

However when I run this workflow it cancels itself automatically with the following error

> RequestorId: 9bbc7b07-1b7c-bd21-cbf1-6c41902fce52. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["48"],"SPRequestGuid":["9bbc7b07-1b7c-bd21-cbf1-6c41902fce52"],"request-id":["9bbc7b07-1b7c-bd21-cbf1-6c41902fce52"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0,
>   private"],"Date":["Thu, 23 Oct 2014 15:49:20
>   GMT"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

The workflow will work if I don't reference the version number, say for example I set the variable to input the text ABCDEF instead of the truncated version number. However once it starts cancelling workflows, no workflows at all will work in the library.

I'm using SP 2013

Thanks

Comment: The version of workflow is 2013?

Comment: Can you get the ULS log generated at the time of the error?

Comment: Yes the workflow is 2013. What is the ULS log and what should I be looking for in the ULS logs?